# AJAX - Not getting a simple php response(returns "undefined")

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I don't know why xmlhttp.response is returning undefined after contacting the php file.

**index.php**

```
    <script language="Javascript">
    var countdown;
    countdown = setInterval(function(){

        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                alert(xmlhttp.responsetext);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","updateindex.php?id=8",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    },3000);

    </script>
```

**updateindex.php**

```
    <?php
    echo "hi";
    ?>
```

It should alert "hi" every 3 seconds, but it alerts "undefined" every 3 seconds.

Comment: does console.log(xmlhttp.responsetext); shows anything (chromedev/firebug panel)?

Comment: is your `updateindex.php?id=8` is right also add alert to you php page and check that `xmlhttp` object requesting your specified url

Comment: Solved, thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

Note the capital T in responseText. So it should be `xmlhttp.responseText`.

Comment: The sad part is it would have taken hours of me staring at it for me to realize this mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @shawna you should select it as an answer so that other could also know if it suits to their problem also

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, "undefined" means the variable you tried to access is not defined, i.e., it doesn't exist. When you see that, you should check right away for typos. In this case,
`xmlhttp.responsetext` should be `xmlhttp.responseText`. The lowercase property you selected does not exist.

In WebKit browsers like Chrome and Safari (and I'm sure in others, but those are the ones I use) you can also check your variable names in the console. Google how to use the developer tools in your browser. When you're having trouble referencing a property on an object like you are now, it's often helpful to type/log the object name into the console, which will then show you a list of all its properties. For instance, if you add `console.log(xmlhttp)` to your script, it will show the object and all its properties in the console, and you can see that the property you want is `responseText`, not `responsetext`.